# oracle invalid format model with comparing dates

Tags: oracle

I am trying to run the following query. I am passing the date from a parameter

```
SELECT to_char(TIMESTAMP, 'HH24') * 1 TIMESTAMP
    ,sum(TwoG) TwoG
    ,sum(ThreeG) ThreeG
    ,sum(FourG) FourG
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM T_CA_Cellsdown

    UNION ALL

    SELECT *
    FROM T_CA_Cellsdown_TFVF
    )
WHERE trunc(TIMESTAMP) = trunc(to_date('03-Apr-16', 'dd-Mon-yy'))
    AND Type = 'Network'
GROUP BY to_char(TIMESTAMP, 'HH24') * 1
ORDER BY to_char(TIMESTAMP, 'HH24') * 1
```

**Error in query: ORA-01481: invalid number format model**

The following query works. I am just trying to change `sysdate` to a date string which I pass as param through user input in php. Why it is being multiplied by 1 I do not know, it is a query that works and provides the required result.

```
SELECT to_char(TIMESTAMP, 'HH24') * 1
    ,sum(TwoG) TwoG
    ,sum(ThreeG) ThreeG
    ,sum(FourG) FourG
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM T_CA_Cellsdown

    UNION ALL

    SELECT *
    FROM T_CA_Cellsdown_TFVF
    )
WHERE trunc(TIMESTAMP) = trunc(sysdate-1)
    AND Type = 'Network'
GROUP BY to_char(TIMESTAMP, 'HH24') * 1
ORDER BY to_char(TIMESTAMP, 'HH24') * 1
```

Comment: What's your NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE (`select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE'`)? What datatype is the column `TIMESTAMP`? I'm going to guess not a date/timestamp? Lastly, why are you multiplying by 1 (shouldn't affect anything but a bit strange)?

Comment: If you want the hours as a number you can `extract(hour from timestamp)`. Simpler than multiplying by 1 to convert it implicitly, or using to_number. What datatype is your timestamp column - sounds obvious, but is it actually a timestamp, or a date, or a string? You can check the NLS settings by querying `NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS`. Check NLS_DATE_FORMAT and NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT while you're there. (And add info to the question).

Comment: how do i find `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`? TIMESTAMP is DATE_TIME

Comment: That's normally a bad idea @Sagi; firstly because of removing the century part of the year and secondly because it'll normally mess up indexing strategies. If something's a date keeping it as a date is always best. In the OPs case either they have an index on `TIMESTAMP` or `trunc(TIMESTAMP)`. In the latter case it's dealt with ,in the former a better query would be `where timestamp >= trunc(sysdate - 1) and timestamp < trunc(sysdate)`

Comment: I wrote that in the comment @Bonez, though Alex has answered it properly anyway and it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the last line:

```
ORDER BY to_char(TIMESTAMP, 'HH24') * 1
```

In the order-by clause it's seeing TIMESTAMP as the column alias from the select list, not as the original TIMESTAMP from the table; so it contains a number, not a timestamp.

So if you had a timestamp where the hours value was 13, say, you're doing

```
ORDER BY to_char(13, 'HH24') * 1`
```

... and as the first argument is a number you're using the numeric version of `TO_CHAR()`, and `HH24` isn't a valid format model for that. Which is what the error message says.

You can just do:

```
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP;
```

To use your original pattern you'd need to supply a table alias for your inline view, and then use that alias in the order-by, to qualify the TIMESTAMP. By default it's using the column alias version.

Comment: I know for some reason I've mixed it up with the other clauses thats why I've delete my comment before you posted yours. But he posted another query with the same order by clause, which works fine.

Comment: @sagi - with the same data both the OP's queries get ORA-01481, so I don't think that's what they were really running already, or they had no matching data (which wouldn't trip over the error), or there's something else they aren't telling us *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole The query with `sysdate -1` has always worked and has been there long before I came. I am trying to make this dynamic in a web app by passing a date value as working out the number of days from `sysdate` to subtract is just more coding work.I assume `trunc` in oracle refers to midnight of the day selected?

Comment: I updated question, original query never had alias and was in excel hardcoded with `sysdate -1`

Comment: @bonez - yes, trunc sets the time to midnight, You don't need to do that with your string value, it's already mightnight. It's the addition of the column alias that has broken the query, as that is taking precedence. But whatever happened before, does this fix the problem with your new query?

Comment: @AlexPoole order by fixed problem, i thought it was my where clause, thanks

Answer (score 0):

`order by` is executed at last. By the time `order by` is executed, you are deriving an new column in select statement as `timestamp`. To overcome it, just use `timestamp` in order by

```
SELECT to_char(TIMESTAMP, 'HH24') * 1 TIMESTAMP
    ,sum(TwoG) TwoG
    ,sum(ThreeG) ThreeG
    ,sum(FourG) FourG
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM T_CA_Cellsdown

    UNION ALL

    SELECT *
    FROM T_CA_Cellsdown_TFVF
    )
WHERE trunc(TIMESTAMP) = trunc(to_date('03-APR-16', 'dd-Mon-yy'))
    AND Type = 'Network'
GROUP BY to_char(TIMESTAMP, 'HH24') * 1
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP  -- TIMESTAMP here refers to derived column at line 1
```

Or use this

```
SELECT to_char(TIMESTAMP, 'HH24') * 1 TIMESTAMP1 -- Or use different alias
    ,sum(TwoG) TwoG 
    ,sum(ThreeG) ThreeG
    ,sum(FourG) FourG
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM T_CA_Cellsdown

    UNION ALL

    SELECT *
    FROM T_CA_Cellsdown_TFVF
    )
WHERE trunc(TIMESTAMP) = trunc(to_date('03-APR-16', 'dd-Mon-yy'))
    AND Type = 'Network'
GROUP BY to_char(TIMESTAMP, 'HH24') * 1
ORDER BY to_char(TIMESTAMP, 'HH24') * 1
```

I replicated the issue here. - This will not work.

```
select  to_char(TIMESTAMP, 'HH24') * 1 TIMESTAMP,sum(col1) from 
(
select sysdate-1 as TIMESTAMP,1 as col1 from dual 
union all
select sysdate-1 as TIMESTAMP,2 as col1 from dual 
)
where trunc(sysdate)=trunc(to_date('04-APR-16','Dd-Mon-YY'))
group by to_char(TIMESTAMP, 'HH24') * 1
order by to_char(TIMESTAMP, 'HH24') * 1
```

But This statement will work.

```
select  to_char(TIMESTAMP, 'HH24') * 1 TIMESTAMP1,sum(col1) from (
select sysdate-1 as TIMESTAMP,1 as col1 from dual 
union all
select sysdate-1 as TIMESTAMP,2 as col1 from dual 
)
where trunc(sysdate)=trunc(to_date('04-APR-16','Dd-Mon-YY'))
group by to_char(TIMESTAMP, 'HH24') * 1
order by to_char(TIMESTAMP, 'HH24') * 1 --As TIMESTAMP is now reflecting the column from inner table.
```

Comment: Can you please explain why your answer actually answers the question? It's difficult to see the differences between your query and the OPs and you haven't stated why the OP is incorrect...

Comment: I mentioned at top of the answer. `order by is executed at last. By the time order by is executed, you are deriving an new column in select statement named timestamp`

Comment: I was also able to replicate the issue and was resolved by using an different column name as alias.